# url from webview iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi I just wanted to know how to extract url from webview after loading the web view with the method [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.nytimes.com"]]];

In this, I am loading the page with nytimes. When the user navigates to the new page I wan to find out the url the moved page. Is there any way I can find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a class to implement the [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), then set an instance of that class to be the delegate of the webview.  The method you will want to implement is:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

In that delegate method, you can get the url by inspecting the `request` property of the web view.

Edit: Changed the recommended delegate method due to Anomie's comment pointing out my failure to see the request propery of UIWebView.

Comment: The loaded request is also a property of the UIWebView.

Comment: I thought it was, so I looked for it, I somehow was blind and did not see it. Looking again, I see it now.  I shall edit my answer to use a more appropriate delegate method.